# Setting min and max values for matrix cells when running a for loop in r

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, max, min

I am running code in a for loop that undertakes some simple arithmetic on individual cells in a matrix.   All cells of the matrix should always have values between 0 and 1.  The values in the matrix should never become negative or exceed 1.   I cannot work out using traditional 'min' and 'max' limit setting how to work this out.

Example data:

```
x<-1:5
y<-runif(length(x)*length(x),0,1)
M<-matrix(y, length(x), length(x))
```

e.g. subtracting 0.01 from every cell  (in my real situation, the 0.01 to be subtracted at each iteration of the loop is from a specific cell and not from every cell as written here, but I think that shouldn't effect how to set the min/max?

```
for (i in 1:50){
M[,]<-M[,]-0.01
}
```

e.g. or if adding 0.01 to every cell of the matrix:

```
for (i in 1:50){
M[,]<-M[,]+0.01
}
```

If returning the matrix after either of these for loops, the values in the matrix will not be contained to within the 0 and 1 range like I desire them to be.  I'm flummoxed as to how to do this.

If I was doing something specific to one 'cell' of the matrix, e.g.

```
for (i in 1:100){
M[3,4]<-M[3,4]-0.01
}
```

would this change how to set min/max values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a clip function

```
clip<-function(x, min=0, max=1) {
    x[x<min]<-min; 
    x[x>max]<-max; 
    x
}
```

This will set all values `<` min to the min, and all values `>` max to max. So if you subtract .9 from every cell, you expect a lot of negatives, but `clip` will change those to 0's

```
 clip(M-.9)
```

same goes for adding .9

```
 clip(M+.9)
```

Or was the problem that you were trying to subtract of the min? When doing something like

```
for (i in 1:50){
    M[,]<-M[,]-0.01
}
```

That statement inside the loop is operating on every element of the vector each time. So you're really subtracting off 0.5. Which is probably too much.

Comment: @BenBolker But we want to find the min/max across all cells. Not rows or columns, right? Or did I misunderstand the question.

Comment: I was just going to define `clip()` as `pmin(max,pmax(min,x))`

Comment: @BenBolker Ah. ok. That now makes sense.

Comment: I have tried implementing this, but without success.  I will keep trying different things.   I have found as a work around solution adding an ifelse() statement works for specific cells.  e.g. adding the line ifelse(M[3,4]<0, M[3,4]<-0, M[3,4]) to prevent row3col4 of the matrix ever going beneath zero in the subtraction case.  For my specific situation, this seems to work. Not sure if it would be a very good general solution to the problem.

Comment: @jalapic What do you mean by "without success"? What exactly is the code you are running and how is it failing?

Comment: The exact code i'm using is v lengthy.  In brief, what I am doing is the following.   For every iteration, I run some code and then two individuals from the matrix are chosen i and j.   I then perform two calcs:  M[i,j]<-M[i,j]+0.01 and M[j,i]<-M[j,i]-0.01 .  Each iteration, i and j are chosen pseudorandomly, meaning that it is likely that some individuals will after not too many iterations have cells that are <0 or >1 (which I don't want them to).   I am now thinking that my question wasn't clear enough and that my approach may not be the best for my code anyway. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @jalapic That's exactly what the clip function was there to help with. I don't understand how it would have failed. Did you reassign? `M<-clip(M+.9)`. Well, if you're going to do something else now, i guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: If it works I won't give up on it!  I will retry. It is likely my mistake.

Comment: success! thanks for your persistence.  I had missed the clip from one line of code leading to the problem.   This solution does indeed work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two ways to do this:

## 1 - post-hoc

Run your loops through and get your results (outside of the range), then force the data to be within your min/max values with:

```
M[which(M<min)] = min
M[which(M>max)] = max
```

## 2 - within the loop

You could modify your assignment function to read

```
for (i in 1:50){
    M[which(M<max)] <- M[which(M<max)]+0.01
}
```

for the addition case and

```
for (i in 1:50){
    M[which(M>min)] <- M[which(M>min)]-0.01
}
```

for the subtraction case.